# Windows 10 Photos App - any way to show open file name on Taskbar?

Tags: windows-10, windows-photo-gallery

I work with hundreds of images daily, flicking through site photographs and importing those that I need into a document as part of my reporting process. It's always worked smoothly (under Windows 7 Pro) to have the photographs open in Windows Photo Gallery on one of my side monitors with the file name conveniently shown on the taskbar, allowing me to locate the photograph of interest in the project folder and drag it into my document.

After updating from Windows 7 Pro to Windows 10 Pro (x64), I have had a strange artifact issue when opening JPGs using Windows Photo Gallery (random white chequered pattern in the upper left quadrant of the image; does not always appear and can often be cleared by zooming/unzooming) and have therefore had to switch to using the new Photos app. Unfortunately Microsoft, in their wisdom, have changed the taskbar name to a static 'Photos' listing rather than the filename of the open image.

The only way by which I can see the open image name now is to open the File Info window in Photos, which introduces a new sidebar with the relevant detail. Unfortunately as my secondary monitors are both portrait 1200x1600, the sidebar drastically reduces the size of the image itself - not ideal, and it's proving a frustration.

Is there any way by which the Photos app can be modified by a registry hack or similar to show the open image filename rather than just 'Photos'? I know this is a pretty unusual complaint so I'm not expecting a solution here, but thought I'd throw it out there anyway in case it's annoying someone smarter than myself too =P

Cheers
- Moph

Comment: I'd love to be able to see the file name like that somehow also. But at least the File Info sidebar is an option and it stays there as you page through images.

Comment: Actually this issue self-resolved at some point ... I'm guessing as part of a Windows update, though I have no idea which.  Sometime around the beginning of this year the Taskbar and window header for the Photos app updated to show "<filename> - Photos" instead of just "Photos".

Comment: Wow, I see that now on mine. I swore it didn't show in the title bar. I just did Windows 10 upgrade. Maybe it changed since I first tried viewing photos after my upgrade, but I can't be 100% sure.

Comment: That's consistent with it being a Windows Update, I guess - the clean upgrade brought down the earlier version of Photos app and then Windows Updates running in the background loaded in the updated version.

Either way, glad yours is also fixed ... it was a minor but incredibly annoying issue =)

Answer (score 0):

after many tries found the trick
just open picture in photos press alt+enter (or view file info) tab on left side open with file info. press arrow key for next pic, this will show file info in task bar aswell

Comment: Please expand your answer with examples or citation.